# Can't fetch Firestore subcollection

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm woking on the app in React + Firebase. My issues is that **sub collection data is undefined**.

My firestore collection:

```
users - XXXXXXXXXX - name: xxxxx
                   ├ image: xxxxx
                   └ shifts - monday - before_noon: true
                                     ├ after_noon: false
                                     └ night: true
```

error:

> Cannot read property 'monday' of undefined

My code:

```
{user.shifts.monday.before_noon}
```

How can I call datas under sub collections in Firestore.

Comment: Is `shifts` the name of the subcollection of the `user` document? Also, can you share the code you sue to fetch a `user` document (without the `shifts`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **subcollection** is not the same as **nested data** in a Firestore document. For nested data, you can access everything from a single document fetch. Example:

```
const db = firebase.firestore();

await db.collection('users').doc('alice').set({
  name: 'Alice',
  shifts: {
    monday: {before_noon: true}
  }
});

// this is "true"
await db.collection('users').doc('alice').get()).data.shifts.monday.before_noon;
```

A **subcollection** on the other hand is an entirely separate collection of documents that is logically related to a parent document. You must fetch subcollections separately from their parent documents:

```
const userRef = db.collection('users').doc('alice');
const shiftsRef = userRef.collection('shifts');

await shiftsRef.doc('monday').set({
  before_noon: true
});

(await userRef.get()).data() // does not include .shifts
(await shiftsRef.get()).docs.map(snap => {
  day: snap.id, data: snap.data()
}); // [{day: 'monday', data: {before_noon: true}}]
```

In general **nested data** should be used when there is a limited amount and you almost always want to fetch it along-side the rest of the data. **Subcollections** should be used when there is lots and lots of nested data (i.e. too big to fit in a document) or the data is not always necessary to fetch along-side the parent data.

Comment: Thank you so much Michael. It's really helpful, and I could understand how firestore subcollections works.